# Python: Getting uncompressed file size of LZ4 file

Tags: python, lz4

I have compressed a large (>10 GB) file using the python lz4 package. I would like to later retrieve the uncompressed file size. Using `lz4.frame.open(file).seek(0,2)` takes a very long time (~13 s).
I created the file using `lz4.frame.open(file, 'wb', source_size=size)` where `size` is the uncompressed file size. I cannot find a way to access this value later. `lz4.frame.get_frame_info()` does not work on `lz4.frame.LZ4FrameFile` objects, unfortunately.
I am using python 3.9.7 and lz4 3.1.3.

Comment: "Availability of source_size" is mentioned here: https://python-lz4.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#storing-the-uncompressed-source-data-size-in-the-frame

Comment: @VPfB: This only tells you what functions/methods accept source_size as an argument, not where it is found as an attribute or other way to retrieve it. The listed functions where it is available are all class instantiations.

Comment: Alas, "Availability of source_size" is not what it seems. Sorry for useless link.

Comment: I wonder if you could mmap the file to get a bytes-compatible object, then use `lz4.frame.get_frame_info()` ?